# VBS Program to set schedule task in window#7

Tags: vbscript

While running, some of the errors I found were due to which the program can create schedule task but that task is not running.
The problems are:

1. In task scheduler in 'when running the task, use the following user account', it is reflecting system rather the same user account like "chm2520"
2. It will not tick on 'run only when user logged on' rather it tick on 'run whether user is logged on or not'.
3. It is configured for "AT service" rather than window #7.
4. I want to set task to run at 9:30 am every day but it is set at 5:30pm (Indian time).
5. It ticks on the option of "if the task is not scheduled to run again, delete it after", which I don't want.

Can anyone solve these problems?

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objNewJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")
errJobCreated = objNewJob.Create _
("\\dataserver1\data001\D\torque.pdf", "********120000.000000-000", _
True , 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16 OR 32 OR 64, , True, JobId)
If errJobCreated <> 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "Error: Task creation failed"
Else
Wscript.Echo "Task created successfully"
End If
```

Comment: Use TS direct rather than through WMI. `Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\"):Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0):If tasks.Count = 0 Then:Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered.":Else:WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count:end if`

Comment: `Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
:TS.Connect("Serenity")
` plus these two lines at the top.

Comment: Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service") 
TS.Connect("Serenity") 
Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\\dataserver1\data001\D\torque.pdf")
Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)
If tasks.Count = 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered."
Else
WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count
end if

Comment: Well it's trying to connect to my computer. Second line is my computer's name.